# Turning a general story idea into a series of events

Tags: plot, structure, planning

I don't tend to struggle coming up with ideas for story plots - the 'one sentence summary', as it were. As soon as it comes to breaking that into a series of events and chapters, though, I quickly get stuck. I know who the main characters are and what problem they're walking into, but when I have to decide what follows from that inciting incident I never know what to do next. Does anyone have any good advice for creating the story timeline?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different frameworks for writing stories.  You'll have to try as many as you can to find what works for you.  This is but one method.

### Yes, but / No, and

Any time your characters try to overcome a problem, it will have one of two outcomes:
"Yes they succeed, but a complication arises", or 
"No they don't succeed, and the consequences of that failure occur."

Examples:

> **Yes** they killed the attacking zombie bear, **but** now they have no ammo left.
>   **No**, they failed to ford the river, **and** now they're soaking wet in the middle of winter
>   **Yes** they managed to dry their clothes off, **but** their fire attracted bandits
>   **No** they failed to steal more ammo, **and** now there is a warrant out for their arrest.
>   **Yes** he managed to win her trust, **but** now he has to pretend he's an FBI agent
>   **No** she failed to reconcile with him, **and** now he won't speak to her.

A good story will have a mixture of both.  By considering the consequences of success you naturally move the story along to a new conflict after the previous one resolves, and considering the prices of failure make sure that the story progresses even as the characters face roadblocks.

Start with some small obstacle, and then run your story until you reach an end.

---

If you're having difficulty thinking in this format, try analyzing an existing story in this style.

> **Yes** the Millenium Falcon reached Alderaan, **but** it isn't there anymore.
>    **No** they failed to escaped the tractor beam, **and** now they're stuck on the Death Star.
>    **Yes** they rescued Leia, **but** now all three of them are cornered.

etc, etc.